# Imagem altera alinhamento de todos componentes dentro de uma div

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um `FORM` dentro de um `DIV`. Nele tenho uma caixa de texto para o usuário entrar com os dados e uma imagem, à direita, para encaminhar os dados.

O problema que venho tendo é que a minha imagem muda o posicionamento da `AddressBar` dentro do container ou simplesmente não fica alinhada com os demais elementos.

```css
.fields label {
  background: #f6a828;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  font: 15px'Open Sans', Arial;
  width: 60px;
}
#Address {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#searchButton {
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  }
```

```html
<form name="addressBar" method="post" action="teste2.html">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="fields">
      <label for="">Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="addressBar" id="Address">
      <input type="image" name="searchButton" id="searchButton" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ44wMLpgbaOufW65LhrFS0gQ0O0k3CxVzCLzD6U1hLMAqDUif3YA">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
<form name="addressBar" method="post" action="teste2.html">
         <fieldset> 
            <div class="fields">
                <label for="">Address</label> 
                <input type="text" name="addressBar" id="Address">
                <input type="image" name="searchButton" id="searchButton" 
                       src="img/searchButton.jpg"> 
            </div> 
         </fieldset> 
    </form>
```

Sem a imagem fica assim:
[image: Address formatação correta]

Comment: Coloca `vertical-align: middle;` no #searchButton.

Comment: @natan Funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: @natan quando quiser responder a uma pergunta utilize a área de resposta e não a própria pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado, como era uma resposta simples não vi necessidade mas acabei de acrescentar uma resposta mais completa, vista que a atual não explicava a propriedade em si.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade `VERTICAL-ALIGN`.

> A propriedade vertical-align  é usada para alinhar elementos de nível
>   inline que estão posicionados ao lado do outro dentro de um elemento de nível bloco.

Artigo completo de  **Sara Soueidan** sobre o assunto: [**Vertical-align**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/vertical-align/) e recomendação do W3C [**Propriedade vertical-align**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

Como seus inputs são posicionados um ao lado do outro (e são de nível inline) e compartilham o mesmo pai `FORM` (de nível bloco) a propriedade é a solução mais simples.

Basta utilizar seu valor `MIDDLE` (Que posiciona o elemento na metade (meio) da vertical com base na `BASELINE` do seu elemento pai) em seu `INPUT` com **ID** `#searchButton`.

```css
.fields label {
  background: #f6a828;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  font: 15px'Open Sans', Arial;
  width: 60px;
}

#Address {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#searchButton {
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  vertical-align: middle; /* AQUI */
}
```

```html
<form name="addressBar" method="post" action="teste2.html">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="fields">
      <label for="">Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="addressBar" id="Address">
      <input type="image" name="searchButton" id="searchButton" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ44wMLpgbaOufW65LhrFS0gQ0O0k3CxVzCLzD6U1hLMAqDUif3YA">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como o @natan comentou, adicione a linha `vertical-align: middle;` na id `searchButton` e do seu CSS, deixando o CSS dessa forma:

```css
.fields label {
  background: #f6a828;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  font: 15px'Open Sans', Arial;
  width: 60px;
}
#Address {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#searchButton {
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<form name="addressBar" method="post" action="teste2.html">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="fields">
      <label for="">Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="addressBar" id="Address">
      <input type="image" name="searchButton" id="searchButton" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ44wMLpgbaOufW65LhrFS0gQ0O0k3CxVzCLzD6U1hLMAqDUif3YA">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

A propriedade determina o alinhamento vertical do texto, e possui os seguintes valores:

1. **baseline** = Coloca o elemento na *baseline* do elemento pai. Se o elemento não tem uma *baseline*, alinha a margem inferior do elemento com a *baseline* do pai.
2. **middle** = Coloca o elemento no ponto mediano da linha, isto é, na *baseline* do pai somado da metade da altura da linha.
3. **sub** = Coloca o elemento abaixo da *baseline* do pai. Esse valor não interfere no tamanho do elemento.
4. **super** = Coloca o elemento acima da *baseline* do pai. Esse valor não interfere no tamanho do elemento.
5. **text-top** = Coloca o elemento no topo dos conteúdos do pai.
6. **text-bottom** = Coloca o elemento na base dos conteúdos do pai.
7. **porcentagem (%)** = Coloca o elemento acima (valores positivos) ou abaixo (valores negativos) com a distancia usada. Usar 0% é o mesmo que usar *baseline*.
8. **comprimento** = Coloca o elemento acima (valores positivos) ou abaixo (valores negativos) com a distancia **exata** usada. Usar 0 é o mesmo que usar *baseline*.

Os próximos dois valores alinham o elemento e seus subelementos.

9. **top** = Coloca o topo dos subelementos alinhados no topo da linha.
10. **bottom** = Coloca a base dos subelementos alinhados na base da linha.

Comment: @natan Editei a pergunta com mais detalhes.